# JavaScript Unit Converter with 2 dropdown menus

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. Trying to build, for practice, a simple unit converter kind of like the one that google uses for converting kilos to pounds, inches to meters, etc.
   I'd like to have an input box for entering the number value. 
After that, two  lists in the HTML files so i can choose in first  the unit i convert from; and on the second  the unit i convert to. 
  Maybe is an obvious one but i have not been able to find an answer to this problem. I'll post the last code/approach i tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="simpleweightconversortest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>

      <!-- Select 1-->
      <label>From:</label>
    <select name="converts" id="Selection">
        <option>Chose Option</option>
        <option value="kilograms1">Kilograms</option>
        <option value="grams1">Grams</option>
        <option value="miligrams1">Miligrams</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Select 2-->
    <label>To:</label>
  <select name="converts2" id="Selection2">
      <option>Chose Option</option>
      <option value="kilograms2">Kilograms</option>
      <option value="grams2">Grams</option>
      <option value="miligrams2">Miligrams</option>
  </select>


<!--INPUT-->
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>Value
    <input type="number" id="value" placeholder="Insert value">

<!--RESULT -->
    <br>Conversion
    <input type="text" id="convertedOuput">

    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="Button" onclick="Conversion()"
    value="convert">
</form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

```
    var val = document.getElementById("value").value;
    var convertedOuput =document.getElementById("convertedOuput");

    var selectFrom = document.getElementById("Selection");
    var selectTo = document.getElementById("Selection2");

    var  madeSelection_1 = selecFrom[selectFrom.selectedIndex].value;
    var  madeSelection_2 = selectTo[selectTo.selectedIndex].value;

  function Conversion() {
    if (madeSelection_1 == "kilograms1" && madeSelection_2 == "kilograms2") {
      var result = val * 1;
      document.getElementById('convertedOuput').innerHTML = result;

    }
}
```

I'm not getting any output in my "conversion" input box. 
What am i doing wrong ? (i'm sure almost everything) Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

`var  madeSelection_1 = selecFrom[selectFrom.selectedIndex].value;`

This should be `selectFrom` and not `selecFrom`.

Also, you need to set the value of the input field using `convertedOuput.value = result` instead of setting its `innerHTML`. (By the way, `convertedOuput` is also misspelled, should be `convertedOutput`, but it's consistent, so it should work anyway.)

And finally, you are checking the selected units outside of the conversion button click handler, so they won't be updated when the user changes the selections in the dropdown. Move the corresponding lines which set `value`, `convertedOuput` and `madeSelection_1` and `madeSelection_2` into the `Conversion` function. (Explanation: Right now, the code is run once upon page load, so the values loaded there will always be the an empty string coming from the `Choose option` option. Afterwards, this part is run every time the button is clicked, so the values will be up to date.)

It works now:

```js
function Conversion() {
  var val = document.getElementById("value").value;
  var convertedOutput = document.getElementById("convertedOutput");

  var selectFrom = document.getElementById("Selection");
  var selectTo = document.getElementById("Selection2");

  var madeSelection_1 = selectFrom[selectFrom.selectedIndex].value;
  var madeSelection_2 = selectTo[selectTo.selectedIndex].value;

  if (madeSelection_1 == "kilograms1" && madeSelection_2 == "kilograms2") {
    var result = val * 1;
    convertedOutput.value = result;

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="simpleweightconversortest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>

    <!-- Select 1-->
    <label>From:</label>
    <select name="converts" id="Selection">
      <option>Chose Option</option>
      <option value="kilograms1">Kilograms</option>
      <option value="grams1">Grams</option>
      <option value="miligrams1">Miligrams</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Select 2-->
    <label>To:</label>
    <select name="converts2" id="Selection2">
      <option>Chose Option</option>
      <option value="kilograms2">Kilograms</option>
      <option value="grams2">Grams</option>
      <option value="miligrams2">Miligrams</option>
    </select>


    <!--INPUT-->
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>Value
    <input type="number" id="value" placeholder="Insert value">

    <!--RESULT -->
    <br>Conversion
    <input type="text" id="convertedOutput">

    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="Button" onclick="Conversion()" value="convert">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Note that you would have found a hint to these things more easily if you had looked into your browser's devtools - there you'd have seen an error about `selecFrom`.

Try pressing F12 in your browser. :-)

Furthermore, in the devtools you can do many powerful things to debug and analyze your code, such as executing arbitrary code at runtime, inspect variables, single-step through your lines of code, etc.

I'd recommend you to watch the [Google Chrome Devtools Crash Course video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4q86IjJFag) to get started!

Comment: Hello. Thanks so much for taking the time to give such a detailed and clear explanation. And for the good will of helping a beginner. I had solved this next day after posting this and i just see the answer now. Sorry for not saying before. I'm loving coding more and more everyday.  And it seems the community is super generous.  Hopefully one day i'll be able to help beginners the way i'm beeing helped now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById('convertedOuput').value = result` should display the result of your function.

Comment: Right. You don't set the HTML of an input, you change its value.